# count values and embed note

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have a database (Grade 7) that consists of test items/questions and a different database (item data) that includes individual students and whether they got the item correct or not (1=correct, 0=incorrect).  I would like to develop a formula that would allow me to count the number of students that scored each of the questions/items incorrect (i.e., 0) in the item database but that would also generate the names of the students in the form of a note in the first database (Grade 7).  These are a copy of the databases:

[Item Analysis Database](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tH5AVhNPzbq_9KndaBw6GHbUO2GKd9rqY2it03phZnI/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Here are some screenshots in case that link to the databases rots in the future:

Database:
[image: Database]

Item Data:
[image: Item Data]

Comment: What have you tried so far? `Count` and `textjoin(filter())` should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this in Excel (which is how the question is tagged) but I think the same functions work in Google Sheets (which is what the file appears to be).

This formula should probably go into cell `L4` and it counts the number of students that passed:

```
=LET(col,MATCH("eitem"&A4,'Item Data'!$1:$1,0),scores,OFFSET('Item Data'!A:A,0,col-1),COUNTIF(scores,1))
```

This formula should probably go into cell `M4` and it lists all the students that passed:

```
=LET(col,MATCH("eitem"&A4,'Item Data'!$1:$1,0),scores,OFFSET('Item Data'!A:A,0,col-1),TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER('Item Data'!B:B,scores=1)))
```

The `LET()` function is useful here because it lets you break the formula into pieces, assigning longer pieces to just a variable name. You could also write this without the `LET()` function but it's harder (for me, at least) to debug.

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET('Item Data'!A:A,0,MATCH("eitem"&A4,'Item Data'!$1:$1,0)-1),1)
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER('Item Data'!B:B,OFFSET('Item Data'!A:A,0,MATCH("eitem"&A4,'Item Data'!$1:$1,0)-1)=1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I'm halfway there.  The syntax for cell L4 and M4 worked perfectly for the first item; however, when I dragged, it returned a value of #N/A for the other items.  How can I fix that? Thank you again!

Comment: @MilagrosGonzalez I see my error. The row reference `1:1` is relative and should have been absolute like this `$1:$1` so Excel doesn't update the reference as you copy / paste down. I have update the answer.

Comment: Perfect! This is amazing!!!!! Thank you sooooo very much!  This has been immensely helpful!